# How to suppress Undefined index error?

Tags: php, error-handling

Before you suggest using `isset` or `empty` or `array_key_exists` -- I know.

I've inherited an old project with close to a million lines of code. I would like to enable `E_NOTICE` but I get flooded with messages. As a temporary solution I've suppressed just "undefined index" errors by doing this:

```
function _global_error_handler($level, $message, $filename, $line_no, $context) {
    if($level===E_NOTICE && substr($message,0,16)==='Undefined index:') return false;
```

But I was hoping there would be some way to disable the notice altogether via an INI setting or something. I don't want the overhead of it calling the global error handler every time this happens.

Comment: So essentially you want to see E_NOTICE messages except "undefined index"? You're turning this back off for production, right? Then who cares about this tiny "overhead" during development?

Comment: I think your current solution is the only way to work around this, so I would keep it like this, and spend the time you saved by doing so on actually fixing the issues. After all, that notice indicates a possible error.

Comment: It might be a domino effect. Try fixing the first error that occurs to see if it fixes subsequent ones.

Comment: @Dagon I'm not sure you understand what a million lines of PHP looks like or that clients don't care how many errors you generate as long as their product works and is delivered on time. I'm doing the best I can here ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to be more specific than the `E_*` constants, short of manually parsing the error condition as you currently are doing.

What I would suggest for now is to disable `E_NOTICE` errors. When you have the opportunity (which should be as soon as reasonably possible), enable them again and go through fixing as many as possible.